# SQL Pivot Grid (Rows to Column

Tags: sql, pivot

Hi im new to pivot tables and i hope you can help me out. I have a table called Additional User Info... It  would be easier to show rather than explain:

Source:

T_Info

(ID No, Field, Value)
1000, Gender, Male
1000, Age, 18
1000, School, MIT

Result That I Want
ID, Gender, Age, School
1000, Male, 18, MIT

is this possible without using a cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IDNo,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Gender' THEN Value END) Gender,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Age' THEN Value END) Age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'School' THEN Value END) School
FROM mytable
GROUP BY IDNo
```